# Add a where-object on a table construct?

Tags: powershell

Renaming the headers with 'label' and I'd like to filter on that last one 'SpaceLeft'. It doesn't work correctly though. For example:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName sfuslt167 -Filter "drivetype=3" |
  Format-Table -Property deviceID,
    @{label='freespace(GB)';expression={$_.freespace / 1GB -as [int]}},
    @{label='Size(GB)';expression={$_.size / 1GB -as [int]}}, 
    @{label='SpaceLeft';expression={$_.freespace / $_.size * 100}} |
      Where-Object {$_.SpaceLeft -lt 10}
```

Results:

```
deviceID freespace(GB) Size(GB)        SpaceLeft
-------- ------------- --------        ---------
C:                 130      237 54.8893461475826
```

This should come back with nothing as the value in 'SpaceLeft' is greater than 10 being specified in the WHERE statement, yet it comes back with results. Why is this??

Comment: your problem is that you used `Format-Table` instead of `Select-Object`. the 1st BUTCHERS the objects and sends out the bloody remains wrapped in _formatting code_. the 2nd sends out a new object with the specified props. ///// that means your `Where-Object` had nothing to work on. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4):

[Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

- **To *transform* data for *further programmatic processing*, use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)** or other data-transformation methods, such as via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object).
- **Only ever use the `Format-*` cmdlets to *format* data *for display***, as their name suggests.

  - PowerShell's great evolutionary leap was to send *objects* rather than *text* through the pipeline, and while `Format-*` cmdlets such as [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) emit objects as well, these objects no longer represent *data*, but *formatting instructions* for [PowerShell's output-formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6) - they serve no other purpose.

Therefore, simply replacing `Format-Table` with `Select-Object` solves your problem:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName sfuslt167 -Filter "drivetype=3" |
  Select-Object -Property deviceID,
    @{label='freespace(GB)';expression={$_.freespace / 1GB -as [int]}},
    @{label='Size(GB)';expression={$_.size / 1GB -as [int]}}, 
    @{label='SpaceLeft';expression={$_.freespace / $_.size * 100}} |
      Where-Object {$_.SpaceLeft -lt 10}
```

What the two cmdlets do have in common, however, is the ability to accept hashtable-based [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) (`@{ label = '...'; expression = { ... } }`), as in your question.

---

As for **what actually happened** in your attempt:

Here's a simplified example, using `Format-Table`:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ freespace = 100; size = 1000 } |
      Format-Table @{label='SpaceLeft'; expression={$_.freespace / $_.size * 100}}

SpaceLeft
---------
       10
```

This *looks* just fine - and indeed that's the purpose - producing a nice *display* representation.

In fact, substituting `Select-Object` for `Format-Table` results in the same *display*:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ freespace = 100; size = 1000 } |
      Select-Object @{ label='SpaceLeft'; expression={$_.freespace / $_.size * 100} }

SpaceLeft
---------
       10
```

The reason is that when command output goes to the *display*, **PowerShell *implicitly, behind the scenes* calls an *appropriate* `Format-*` cmdlet**, which in this case is `Format-Table`.
In other words, the command above is equivalent to the following command:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ freespace = 100; size = 1000 } |
      Select-Object @{label='SpaceLeft'; expression={$_.freespace / $_.size * 100}} |
        Format-Table 

SpaceLeft
---------
       10
```

For the **logic behind *which* `Format-*` cmdlet is chosen *when***, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152594/45375).

However, instead of the (implicitly) applied `Format-Table`, you could have chosen a different formatting cmdlet, such as `Format-List` for list-style display that shows each property on its own line:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ freespace = 100; size = 1000 } |
      Select-Object @{label='SpaceLeft'; expression={$_.freespace / $_.size * 100}} |
        Format-List

SpaceLeft : 10
```

---

However, when it comes to *further processing*, `Select-Object` and `Format-Table` are *not* created equal - only `Select-Object` is suitable:

Let's look at what properties the output object(s) possess, using `Get-Member -Type Properties`, first with `Select-Object`:

```
PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ freespace = 100; size = 1000 } |
      Select-Object @{label='SpaceLeft'; expression={$_.freespace / $_.size * 100}} |
        Get-Member -Type Properties).Name
SpaceLeft
```

As expected, the output has one property, named `SpaceLeft`, and that's what your `Where-Object` call can operate on.

Using `Format-Table` instead of `Select-Object` tells a different story:

```
PS> ([pscustomobject] @{ freespace = 100; size = 1000 } |
      Format-Table @{label='SpaceLeft'; expression={$_.freespace / $_.size * 100}} |
        Get-Member -Type Properties).Name
autosizeInfo
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd
groupingEntry
pageFooterEntry
pageHeaderEntry
shapeInfo
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd
groupingEntry
shapeInfo
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd
formatEntryInfo
outOfBand
writeStream
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd
groupingEntry
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd
groupingEntry
```

It doesn't really matter what these in part obscurely named properties specifically represent - all that matters is:

- Their sole purpose is to be interpreted by PowerShell's output-formatting system.
- The selected / calculated properties passed to `Format-Table` are *not* present as such in the output.

  - That's why your `Where-Object` call didn't work as intended: `$_.SpaceLeft` referenced a non-existing property, so the expression evaluates to `$null`, and `$null -lt 10` is *always* `$true`.

Irrespective of their input, `Format-*` cmdlets output instances of  [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.internal.format) types that represent *formatting instructions*.