# How to insert new data into an existing file?

Tags: powershell

I have problem to insert new data into existing file. The data must be placed at the end of the row.

Data to added:

```
1   255     1   0
```

I tried this way but couldn't.

```
| foreach { $_ + "`t 1 `t 255 `t 1 `t 0" }
```

Here is my code right now:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\.csv"| Select-Object "Person ID","Time" | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize | Out-File C:\Users\.csv
```

End Result:

```
1005   2019-02-01 06:44:31     1   255 1   0
```

Comment: Instead of formatting, just pass along after Select-Object. Also, instead of out-file, use export-csv - depending on the csv format

Comment: Only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets for _display formatting_, never for _programmatic processing_ - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375