# Changing Powershell output from List view to an array view

Tags: powershell, format

I am trying to convert a PowerShell cmdlet's output from a table view, into something more like an array. I used a list format to cut as much junk data as possible. Currently, I use the following code to get this output:

```
Get-AccountsWithUserRight -Right SeNetworkLogonRight | Format-List -Property SID |Set-Variable -Name "Accounts"
$Accounts
```

Output:

```
SID : S-1-5-32-583

SID : S-1-5-32-551

SID : S-1-5-32-545

SID : S-1-5-32-544
```

I am unsure of how to use formatting/other properties to cut out the 'SID' string, and just return an output such as "S-1-5-32-583,S-1-5-32-551,etc". I need to do this as I wish to use the output in another cmdlet, and the extra data is causing errors.

Answer (score 2):

Only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets for *display formatting*; never use them if data must be *programmatically processed*.
`Format-*` cmdlets output *formatting instructions*, not *data* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).

Also, to save output in a variable, it's simpler to assign to it rather than to use `Set-Variable`:

```
# Save the account objects in a variable.
$Accounts = Get-AccountsWithUserRight -Right SeNetworkLogonRight
```

If you then want to output / use just the SID values, taking advantage of [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration):

```
$Accounts.SID
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread and the original poster has moved on, but others might look at this, so here's a version that I think answers the original question all the way.  My understanding is that he wants a variable to have all the SIDs in an array.

```
$Accounts = Get-AccountsWithUserRight -Right SeNetworkLogonRight | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SID

#OR

$Accounts = Get-AccountsWithUserRight -Right SeNetworkLogonRight | ForEach-Object { $_.SID }
```

Either one should give you what you wanted.  The Accounts variable should now only have the SID without any other properties.  I usually use the second example, but I've seen a lot of cases with the first one.