# How to capture value from a PS expression?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to put together an expression that returns a bare value, *without* a table or name of the expression included.

For example, I have this line from another solution:

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'" |
  Format-Table @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}}
```

This returns:

```
 Size
 ----
475.33
```

How can I grab just the 475.33?

Comment: `gwmi win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'" | Select-Object -Property @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Size`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table`:

```
$DiskC = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'" | Select-Object @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}}

$DiskC.Size
```

Answer (score 0):

- `Format-*` cmdlets return objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375). In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*.
- `gwmi` is the built-in alias for the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet, which is obsolete.
  The CIM cmdlets (e.g., [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance)) superseded the WMI cmdlets in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell [Core] v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).
- If you simply want to *calculate a value* derived from (each of) your input object(s), use the [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet.

Therefore:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'" | ForEach-Object {
  [math]::Round($_.Size / 1gb, 2)
}
```

Or, more simply, using an expression:

```
[math]::Round(
  (Get-CimInstance win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'").Size / 1gb, 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use your first line:

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'" | Format-Table @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}}
```

But Pipe it trough Select-object instead of format table then pipe it again to select object expanding the property (or just .size)

```
  gwmi win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'" | Select @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}} | select -ExpandProperty Size
```