# How to display pscustomobject in a loop?

Tags: powershell

I have the following pscutomobject

```
$output = [PSCustomObject]@{
    '#' = ''
    'Report Path' = ''
    'Schedule ID' = ''
    Status = ''
}
```

i have a foreach loop and i add values for each iteration into the pscustomobject

```
foreach ($refreshSchedulePlanId in $reportRefreshScheduleSubscriptionIdDataWithoutHeader)
{
    $output.'#' = $iteration
    $output.'Report Path' = $($reportRefreshScheduleSubscriptionIdDataWithoutHeader[$loopCount])
    $output.'Schedule ID' = $refreshSchedulePlanId
    $output.Status = $status

    $output | ft
}
```

but its outputting this way:

```
# Report Path Schedule ID Status
1 report1/rep1 0998989898 success

# Report Path Schedule ID Status
2 report2/re2 76767868767 fail
```

it should output:

```
# Report Path Schedule ID Status
1 report1/rep1 0998989898 success
2 report2/re2 76767868767 fail
```

etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `ft` ([`Format-Table`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/)) *inside your loop*, each custom object is formatted instantly, individually, printing as a complete table - complete with header - every time.

The *immediate* fix is to move the `ft` call out of the loop and apply it to the whole loop:

```
& { 
  foreach ($refreshSchedulePlanId in $reportRefreshScheduleSubscriptionIdDataWithoutHeader)
  {
    $output.'#' = $iteration
    $output.'Report Path' = $($reportRefreshScheduleSubscriptionIdDataWithoutHeader[$loopCount])
    $output.'Schedule ID' = $refreshSchedulePlanId
    $output.Status = $status

    $output
  }
} | ft
```

Note: Since a `foreach` loop is a *statement*, it can't be used as-is in a pipeline, and is therefore wrapped in a script block (`{ ... }`) invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-).

However, since your `[pscustomobject]` instances have only *4* properties, you do not need `ft` (`Format-Table` at all, because PowerShell by default uses table formatting with custom objects that have *4 or fewer* properties.

Not using a `Format-*` cmdlet has the added advantage that the output remains suitable for *further programmatic processing*, given that `Format-*` cmdlets are only ever useful for *display formatting*, given that the objects they return are *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).