# Converting List to String Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get a users assigned Licenses.

Using `Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN |Format-List Licenses` I have a list that looks something like this: `Licenses : {testmailorg:FLOW_FREE, testmailorg:M365EDU_A3_FACULTY}`

I want be able to get the licenses from this as an individual strings such as "M365EDU_A3_FACULTY"

So far I have been unable to achieve this using `foreach` or `for` loops.

Is there anyway to do this, or even a different way to get users Licenses?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN).Licenses` ?

Comment: the code posted by Theo will give you the values as strings in an array [if there is more than one]. once you have that, you can split on the `:`, take the last part, and `-join ','` to have a coma delimited string with all those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to be clear: `Format-*` cmdlets output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375). In short: **only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing***.

Here, the formatted output tells you that the information of interest is contained in the `.Licenses` property, so, as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) points out, you can simply access the property value by enclosing the command in `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

```sh
# Outputs the .Licenses property value of the object output by Get-MsolUser.
(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN).Licenses
```

As the property name (and the formatted output) implies, `.Licenses` contains a *collection* of objects (possibly strings), and to extract only the part of each (stringified) object *after* the `testmailorg:` prefix, you need to use text parsing, as [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) advises; here, the simplest approach is to use PowerShell's regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375), which can directly operate on *collections* and performs string replacement on *each element*:

```
PS> (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN).Licenses -replace '^.+:'
FLOW_FREE
M365EDU_A3_FACULTY
```

Note: If the LHS is a *collection* (array), the result of the `-replace` operation is a corresponding *array* (`[object[]]`) of the transformed strings.