# Problem when uninstall direct from msi location path & in for loop

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, installation, windows-installer

I try to uninstall a msi file, but when I try this via array I get an error (cant find installation package)

When I do the same but not in array - it works

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $msiArrayClean.length; $i++){
  
        Write-Host $msiArrayClean[$i]
        & msiexec.exe /x $msiArrayClean[$i]

}
```

[here the output of Write Host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogCze.png)

How i come to $msiArrayClean

```
 $msiCache = get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Where-Object Name -like "*7-Zip*"  | Format-Table LocalPackage -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders
    $msiString = $msiCache | Out-String
    $msiArrayWithEmptyLines = $msiString -split "`n"
    $msiArray = $msiArrayWithEmptyLines.Split('', [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    $msiArrayCleanString = $msiArray | Out-String
    $msiArrayClean = $msiArrayCleanString -split "`n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few caveats up front:

- `Format-*` cmdlets output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375). In short: **only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing***.
- The **CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3** (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because *PowerShell (Core)* (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).
- **Use of the `Win32_Product` WMI class is discouraged**, both for reasons of performance and due to potentially unwanted side effects - see [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/admin-development/windows-installer-reconfigured-all-applications).

  - An alternative - available in *Windows PowerShell* only (not in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*) - is to use the following to get uninstall command lines and execute them via `cmd /c`:

    ```
    Get-Package -ProviderName Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller | 
      ForEach-Object { $_.meta.attributes['UninstallString'] }
    ```

---

If you need to stick with `Win32_Product`:

```
# Get the MSI package paths of all installed products, where defined.
$msiCache = (Get-CimInstance Win32_Product).LocalPackage -ne $null

foreach ($msiPackagePath in $msiCache) {
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $msiPackagePath) {
    # Note that msiexec.exe runs *asynchronously*.
    # Use Start-Process -Wait to wait for each call to complete.
    & msiexec.exe /x $msiPackagePath
  } else {
    Write-Warning "Package not found: $msiPackagePath"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like reaching to WMI, since its perfomance is the issue. I prefer to do it via registry and it worked for me many times. Code explanation in comments.

```
$name = "7-zip"

#Get all items from registry
foreach ($obj in Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") {
    #Get DisplayName property of registry
    $dname = $obj.GetValue("DisplayName")
    #Search for given name
    if ($dname -like "*$name*") {
        #Get uninstall string (it gets you msiexec /I{APPID})
        $uninstString = $obj.GetValue("UninstallString")
        foreach ($line in $uninstString) {
            #Getting GUID from "{" to "}""
            $found = $line -match '(\{.+\}).*'
            if ($found) {
                #If found - get GUID
                $appid = $matches[1]
                Write-Output "About to uninstall app $appid"
                #Start uninstallation
                Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $appid /qb" -Wait
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Added solution with msi path after Nehat's comment as this works for me (I tried to minimize the code :))

```
$msiCache = get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Where-Object Name -like "*7-Zip*"  | Format-Table LocalPackage -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders

foreach ($msi in $msiCache | Out-String) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($msi)) {
        continue
    }
    Write-Host $msi
    Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/x $msi" -Wait
}
```

Comment: Nice Solution, but in my case I need the Path to the cached msi File because : some APPs which are installed need the original MSI file when you want to uninstall - that's why I do it via wmi

Comment: Thanks you for your support: I get the same message (Installation Package could not be found - but its there ) - when you have some idea, please let me know - thanks for optimizing the code :)