# PowerShell to add dash symbols at beginning of line output from Get-ComputerInfo

Tags: powershell

I would like to add an asterisk to the beginning of liner in output:

```
$SYSLST1 = "OsName","OsVersion","TimeZone","CsName"
$X = (Get-ComputerInfo -Property $SYSLST1 | Format-List | Out-String).Trim()
$Y = ForEach ($Z in $X){
$Z.insert(0,"  * ")
}
Write-Host $Y
```

But it's only doing the first line:

```
  * OsName    : Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
OsVersion : 10.0.14393
TimeZone  : (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
CsName    : SIS-2016-INT-ST
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need the `-Stream` switch to instruct [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) to output *individual lines*** - by default, you'll get a *single*, *multi-line* string.

Also, you can simplify your string-insertion task with the help of the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

```sh
(
  Get-ComputerInfo -Property $SYSLST1 | Format-List | Out-String -Stream
).Trim() -ne '' -replace '^', '  * '
```

- `-ne ''` filters out the empty lines that result from calling `.Trim()` on all output lines (via [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)).
- `-replace '^', '  * '`, replaces the start of the string (`^`) with the specified string, in effect inserting it at the beginning of each line.

Generally speaking, note that `Format-*` cmdlets output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's output-formatting system (which in your case are interpreted by `Out-String`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).

In short: **use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display***, not for subsequent *programmatic processing*.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @mklement0's answer --

In my experience, PowerShell works best when you can *defer formatting* until the very end -- i.e. all processing should be done on *objects*, and then the final task is rendering *strings*.

Starting at the most basic script:

```
Get-ComputerInfo -Property $SYSLST1
```

```
OsName                                 OsVersion  TimeZone                               CsName
------                                 ---------  --------                               ------
Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0.17763 (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) WIN-IJ0UD3SK4HR
```

The result is a single `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` and by default, the object is run through `Format-Table`

A cool trick of `PSCustomObject` is that you can iterate over its properties:

```
 $(Get-ComputerInfo -Property $SYSLST1).PSObject.Properties |
   ForEach-Object { "  *  $($_.Name) : $($_.Value))" }
```

```
  *  OsName : Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard)
  *  OsVersion : 10.0.17763)
  *  TimeZone : (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada))
  *  CsName : WIN-IJ0UD3SK4HR)
```

This gives us full control over the string rendering and allows us to make tweaks to it without fear of breaking other parts of the script.