# How can I get the number of CPU cores in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, cpu

Suppose I'm running a (power)shell on a Windows machine.

Is there a one-liner I could use to get:

1. The number of physical processor cores and/or
2. The max number of in-flight threads, i.e. cores * hyper-threading factor?

Note: I want just a single number as the command output, not any headers or text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note:

- The answer below assumes a *single* processor (socket) with *multiple cores*.
- Note: The following is gleaned from the documentation; I cannot personally verify it. According to documentation of the [`Win32_Processor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor#remarks) CIM/WMI class, an instance of that class exists for *each processor (socket)*, so if your system has multiple processors (each with multiple cores) installed, use something like the following to get the *total* count of *logical* cores (`. NumberOfLogicalProcessors`); use `.NumberOfCores` for the *physical* cores:

  ```bash
  $totalLogicalCores = (
   (Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors |
     Measure-Object -Sum
  ).Sum
  ```

  - Note that there's also a `.NumberOfEnabledCores` property (Windows 10+, Windows Server 2016+), which refers to *enabled physical* cores, according to the docs. There's seemingly no distinct property for the hyperthreading multiplication factor, so in order to determine the *enabled logical* core count, you may have to to use `.NumberOfEnabledCores * (.ThreadCount / .NumberOfCores`)

---

[Ran Turner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7494218/ran-turner) provides the crucial pointer, but can be improved in two ways:

- The CIM cmdlets (e.g., [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance)) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even *have* them anymore. Note that WMI still *underlies* the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).
- [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table), as all `Format-*` cmdlets, is designed to produce *for-display formatting*, for the *human observer*, and *not* to output data suitable for later *programmatic processing* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information).

  - To instead create *objects* with a *subset* of the input objects' properties, use the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet. (If the output object(s) have 4 or fewer properties and aren't captured, they *implicitly* format as if `Format-Table` had been called; with 5 or more properties, it is implicitly `Format-List`).

Therefore:

```bash
# Creates a [pscustomobject] instance with 
# .NumberOfCores and .NumberOfLogicalProcessors properties.
$cpuInfo =
  Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_Processor | 
     Select-Object -Property NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors

# Save the values of interest in distinct variables, using a multi-assignment.
# Of course, you can also use the property values directly.
$coreCountPhysical, $coreCountLogical = $cpuInfo.NumberOfCores, $cpuInfo.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

Of course, if you're only interested in the *values* (CPU counts as mere numbers), you don't need the *intermediate* object and can omit the `Select-Object` call above.

As for a *one-liner*:

If you want a one-liner that creates distinct variables, without repeating the - costly - `Get-CimInstance` call, you can use an aux. variable that takes advantage of PowerShell's ability to use assignments *as expressions*:

```bash
$coreCountPhysical, $coreCountLogical = ($cpuInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor).NumberOfCores, $cpuInfo.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

- To save the numbers in distinct variables *and* output them  (return them as a 2-element array), enclose the entire statement in `(...)`.
- To *only* output the numbers, simply omit the `$coreCountPhysical, $coreCountLogical =` part.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `[Environment]::ProcessorCount` to get the logical processor count. It works on non-Windows as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount

Answer (score 3):

```
$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
```

gives number of processors.
Works also when you have more than one socket in use

Comment: So, if I have 3 sockets with 5 cores per socket and a "hyperthreading factor" of 2 - what would this show me?

Answer (score 2):

To find out processor number of cores using PowerShell

`Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor | ft NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors`

To find out what is the number of threads running:

`(Get-Process|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Threads).Count`

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) (v6+), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: @mklement0: So, how do I get the number of physical/logical cores using Get-CimInstance, then?

Comment: Same class, and almost the exact same syntax. Run `Get-Help Get-CimInstance` to see the proper syntax, but it should be: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_processor | Select NumberofCores`

Comment: `Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_Processor | Format-Table -Property NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors`

Answer (score 1):

There are several comments with similar answers. `Get-WmiObject` is deprecated. Go with `Get-CimInstance`. Do not use aliases in scripts. Spell commands and parameters out. Explicit is better than implicit.

```
Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_Processor | Format-Table -Property NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want only a single number value assigned to a variable.

```
$NumberOfCores = (Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_Processor).NumberOfCores
$NumberOfLogicalProcessors = (Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
```