# Change content of a file based on a content of another file

Tags: powershell

I have this file structure

[image]

In PowerShell my location is set to `Folder`. `SubSubFolders` has a lot of xml files, and I want to add a line there only if content of `version.txt` file is `a` and that line doesn't exist there already.

I was able to figure out how to change an xml file in particular `SubSubFolder`, but I can't do it when I start in `Folder` folder and and taking into consideration `version`

```
#here I need to add: only if version.txt content of xml file in parent folder is "a"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter *blah.xml -Recurse | Where{!(Select-String -SimpleMatch "AdditionalLine" -Path $_.fullname -Quiet)} | Format-Table FullName

foreach($file in $files)
{
    (Get-Content $file.FullName | Foreach-Object {  $_
                                                if ($_ -match "AdditionalLineAfterThisLine")
                                                {
                                                    "AdditionalLine"
                                                }
    }) | Set-Content $file.FullName
}
```

Comment: As an aside: `Format-*` cmdlets output objects whose sole purpose is to provide _formatting instructions_ to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375). In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data _for display_, never for subsequent _programmatic processing_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for the following:

```
$files = (
  Get-ChildItem -Filter *blah.xml -Recurse | 
    Where-Object{
      -not ($_ | Select-String -SimpleMatch "AdditionalLine" -Quiet) -and
      (Get-Content -LiteralPath "$($_.DirectoryName)/../version.txt") -eq 'a'
    }
).FullName
```

Note that the assumption is that the `version.txt` file contains just *one* line. If it contains multiple lines, the `-eq 'a'` operation would act *as a filter* and return all lines whose content is `'a'`, which in the implied Boolean context of `-and` would yield `$true` if one or more such lines, potentially among others, exist.

Comment: @EricKlaus, my bad: please see my update. (The negation must indeed be applied to the `Select-String` call as a whole, as in your original approach; combining `-NotMatch` with `-Quiet` doesn't work as I expected.)