# remove all characters in every line starting from the character "\" in a text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 50 lines text file ($file1) like and i need to remove the characters starting from an specific character "/" until,the end of the line.

Sample text file:

```
| Area | vserver | file-id |connection-id | session-id | open-mode | path |

| manphsan01 | manphs101 | 9980 | 4278018043 | 5065142205921760710 | rw | Share01\Mandaue\Data01 |

| manphsan01 | manphs101 | 1790 | 4278020659 | 5065142205921763223 | rwd | FinanceDept\ARCHIVING |

| manphsan01 | manphs101 | 1824 | 4278020659 | 5065142205921763223 | rwd | Share01\Cebu\Year2022 |

| manphsan01 | manphs101 | 1976 | 4278020659 | 5065142205921763223 | rwd | SGSDept\General\Document |
```

My desired output sh0uld be like:

```
| Area | vserver | file-id |connection-id | session-id | open-mode | path |

| manphsan01 | manphs101 | 9980 | 4278018043 | 5065142205921760710 | rw | Share01 |

| manphsan01 | manphs101 | 1790 | 4278020659 | 5065142205921763223 | rwd | Finance |

| manphsan01 | manphs101 | 1824 | 4278020659 | 5065142205921763223 | rwd | Share01 |

| manphsan01 | manphs101 | 1976 | 4278020659 | 5065142205921763223 | rwd | SGSDept |
```

the command i used is like this:

```
$var = Get-content $file1

$var.Substring(0, $var.IndexOf('\')) | FT -AutoSize or 

$var.Substring(0, $var.IndexOf('backslash')) | FT -AutoSize
```

My command will work if my data is only 1 line but multiple lines it wont work. I am not sure why the 'backslash' is not showing on the command when i posted it.

ny ideas how to make this work?

Comment: i found a way to do it using foreach procedure.  $a = Get-content $file1

Foreach($line in $a){

$line.Substring(0,$line.IndexOf('\'))

}

Comment: If you have already solved the problem, mind as well [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,of%20the%20Ask%20Question%20page.&text=Alternatively%2C%20you%20may%20go%20back,48%20hours%20to%20do%20so.)

Comment: [1] Your example shows a CSV format complete with headers. PLease open it in Notepad and copy the first couple of lines. Then paste that in your question so we can see what delimiter is used. [2] You say you want to remove _"until,the end of the line"_, but your question clearly shows you want to keep the final `|`, so I believe what you show us is **not** what the file actually looks like. [3] Bear in mind that using `.IndexOf()` can return -1 if the character you're looking for is not found and directly combining that with `.Substring()` wil throw an exception.

Comment: As an aside: `$var.IndexOf('backslash')` looks for substring `backslash` _verbatim_ .

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with *plain-text* processing if you can assume that only *one* field on each line of your *structured* text file contains `\` and that it and everything after it - up until the next field delimiter,  `|` - should be removed:

```
# Transforms all matching lines and outputs them.
# Pipe to Set-Content to save back to a file; use -Encoding as needed.
(Get-Content $file) -replace '\\.+?(?= \|)'
```

The above uses a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation with a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) to remove the unwanted part of matching lines (lines that don't match are passed through as-is).

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/6hY3Lb/1).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `$var = Get-content $file1` stores the individual lines of file `$file1` as an *array* in variable `$var1`.
- To process the resulting lines one by one, you need a *loop* construct, such as a [`foreach` *statement*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) or the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*; e.g. `foreach ($line in $var) { ... }`
- While `$line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf('\'))` works in principle, it will cause a statement-terminating error (exception) for every `$line` value that contains no `\` character, as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) notes, notably with your file's *header* line.

  - While this could easily be fixed with `try { $line.Substring(0, $line.IndexOf('\')) } catch { $line }`, the bigger problem is that it would remove everything *through the end of the line*, which contradicts your desired output, which shows that the next *field seprator*,  `|` should be retained.
  - The above `-replace` operation fixes both these problems; note that it *implicitly* loops over the array of input lines and performs the replacement operation on each, returning an array of (potentially) transformed lines.
- Also note that a formatting cmdlet such as `Format-Table` (`-FT`) should only be used for *for-display* output; it doesn't produce usable *data* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information; also, it has no formatting effect on *strings*.