# Powershell How to extract class member's value

Tags: powershell, loops, object

The following code yields the value I want.

```
PS> $tt = gci -Path \\Munis2\musys_read\export_test\* -Include "ARLMA_*.csv" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending
PS> $ticks = $tt[0].LastWriteTime | Format-Custom @{expr={$_.Date.Ticks};depth=1}
PS> $ticks

class DateTime
{
  $_.Date.Ticks = 637819488000000000
}
```

That value is `$_.Date.Ticks`

I have been searching for ways to extract this value, and cannot come up with a way to do it.

Comment: I asked on your other question, this might be what you're looking for `| Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime, @{n = 'Ticks';e = { $_.LastWriteTime.Date.Ticks }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
$ticks = $tt[0].LastWriteTime.Date.Ticks
```

Note: Thanks to PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) feature, applying `.Date.Ticks` to *multiple* input objects would work too (`(...).Date.Ticks`, where `...` represents a command that outputs multiple `[datetime]` instances).

Alternatively - more slowly, but in a streaming fashion - pipe to 
`... | ForEach-Object { $_.Date.Ticks }`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

The **sole purpose of `Format-*` cmdlets is to output objects that provide *formatting instructions*** to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).

In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*.

Comment: Very helpful. Now, that syntax makes sense, and you're right that I should have associated Format with display, not calculating. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @octopusgrabbus; my pleasure. Please also see my update. Santiago's comment shows you the _data_ equivalent to your approach: using _`Select-Object`_ with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties).