# Powershell: how do I get the current volume as a single letter

Tags: powershell

I would like to have the current volume name as part of a filename, e.g. bsps-on-c.txt for files in volume C:, bsp-on-d.txt for files in volume d and so on.

code is:

```
$v=volume
$col=@{expression="driveletter";label=""}
$v | where {$_.drivetype -like "Fixed" -and  $_.driveletter -notlike "" } | format-table $col
```

output is:

```
-
C
```

question is:
How to get rid off empty lines and line with -

Expectation was:

only letter C and nothing more, no white spaces, no empty lines

Comment: If your plan is to use the _value_ and not just see it as _output_, you should either expand the property using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` or `ForEach-Object -MemberName`

Comment: The linked duplicate discusses how to extract a single property value _as data_ - Mathias' answer shows one approach, Maximilian's comment mentions another. By contrast, `Format-*` cmdlets output objects whose sole purpose is to provide _formatting instructions_ to PowerShell's output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375). In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data _for display_, never for subsequent _programmatic processing_.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to output the drive letter on its own:

```
Get-Volume |Where-Object {$_.DriveType -like "Fixed" -and  $_.DriveLetter -notlike "" } |ForEach-Object DriveLetter
```

`ForEach-Object DriveLetter` will attempt to resolve the `DriveLetter` property on each input object and return its raw value.

Comment: I had to recognize, that the question was not clear enough. What I need ist the __current__ volume of the disk, usb-stick, DVD ..., where the actual script is running. 

I would like to have the _current_ volume name as part of a filename, e.g. bsps-on-c.txt for files in volume C:, bsp-on-d.txt for files in volume d and so on.