# Format-Table renders properties inaccessible

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I want to make use of `Format-Table` to neatly format some properties. This works fine, but once I've called `Format-Table` on an object, I'm unable to access any of the properties for future use.

```
$VersionInfo = Get-ComputerInfo -Property "*version"
$VersionInfo.OsVersion
```

Output:

```
10.0.19042
```

```
$VersionInfoFT = Get-ComputerInfo -Property "*version" | Format-Table
$VersionInfoFT.OsVersion
```

Output:

```
<empty>
```

Comment: `Format-*` are for **display purposes only**. If you actually want to process data further, you should leave that out

Comment: If you want to work with the data later.  Try for something like array of custom objects or array of hashtables.

Comment: Additional background info to complement Theo's comment and zett42's answer: `Format-*` cmdlets output objects whose sole purpose is to provide _formatting instructions_ to PowerShell's output-formatting system. In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data _for display_, never for subsequent _programmatic processing_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenters wrote, the `Format-*` cmdlets are for **display purposes only**. They output *formatting instructions* which produce richly formatted output only when it ends up in the console or at another "end point" (i. e. any of the `Out-*` cmdlets). These instructions generally can't be used to get back to the original data.

You normally keep the **unformatted** objects in a variable for further processing:

```
$VersionInfo = Get-ComputerInfo -Property "*version"
$VersionInfo.OsVersion
```

Now you *can* store the formatting data in another variable as you did before (`$VersionInfoFT = $VersionInfo | Format-Table`), but it usually doesn't make much sense. Typically you either output formatted information immediately or convert it to string.

```
# Format and output only the OsVersion property
$VersionInfo | Format-Table OsVersion

# Format and convert to string with indentation 
$VersionInfoStr = ($VersionInfo | Format-List | Out-String -Stream) -join "`n    "
Write-Verbose "All version info:$VersionInfoStr"
```

In the last example it makes sense to store the formatted output as string, to reduce the complexity of the `Write-Verbose` call. This is done by piping to the `Out-String` cmdlet which basically produces the same output as you see in the console, as a string. The `-Stream` argument is used to split the resulting string into separate lines, so we can rejoin them to produce indented output.