# powershell results - return rows with values only

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

i have this powershell that i am looking to tweak so it only gives me lines with a snapshot and timestamp. At the moment its giving me all virtual machines, with or without a snapshot. I just want to filter it so i get VMs with a snapshot only and associated timestamp, i guess which ever will work to filter for VMs with a snapshot

```
Get-VM | Format-Table -AutoSize VMName, @{Name="TotalSnapshots";Expression={(Get-VMSnapshot -VM $_ | Measure-Object).Count}},@{Name="TimeStamp";Expression={(Get-VMSnapshot -VM $_ | Select-Object CreationTime).CreationTime}}
```

[image]

Comment: Use a Where statement "TotalSnapshots > 0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) instead of [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table), which allows you to filter by these properties via `Where-Object`:

```bash
Get-VM | 
  Select-Object VMName, @{Name="TotalSnapshots";Expression={(Get-VMSnapshot -VM $_ | Measure-Object).Count}},@{Name="TimeStamp";Expression={(Get-VMSnapshot -VM $_).CreationTime}} |
  Where-Object TotalSnapshots -gt 0 |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Note that `Select-Object` constructs and outputs *data* objects, whereas `Format-Table`, as all `Format-*` cmdlets do, outputs objects that are *formatting instructions*, which are only meaningful to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.