# Convert Single Line to Multiple Lines

Tags: powershell, url-rewriting, output

I am new to this Powershell.

I am trying to learn how to modified output.

When I run "Write-output $result | format-list" I have the following output

---

```
userDetails     : @{id=AA:BB:CC:DD:11:22; connectionStatus=CONNECTED; hostType=WIRELESS;
                  authType=WPA2/WPA3+802.1x/FT-802.1x}
connectedDevice : {@{deviceDetails=}}
```

---

How do I rewrite this output to below using powershell 7.2 ? I would like to have

---

```
userDetails     : 
connectionStatus= CONNECTED
hostType        = WIRELESS
authType        = WPA2/WPA3+802.1x/FT-802.1x

connectedDevice :
```

---

Thank you for your help.

Comment: don't use format cmdlets. You may start with `$result | Select-Object -ExpandProperty userDetails`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that produces output close to your desired output:

```sh
# Create sample data
$result = [pscustomobject] @{ 
   userDetails = [pscustomobject]@{ id="AA:BB:CC:DD:11:22"; connectionStatus="CONNECTED"; hostType="WIRELESS"; authType="WPA2/WPA3+802.1x/FT-802.1x"}
   connectedDevice = [pscustomobject]@{ deviceDetails=$null }
}

# Produce output
"userDetails      :"
($result.userDetails | 
    Format-List -Property connectionStatus, hostType, authType | 
    Out-String).Trim() -replace '(?m)(?<=^[^:]+):', '='

"`nconnectedDevice  :"
# TODO: add similar code as for .userDetails
```

Output:

```text
userDetails      :
connectionStatus = CONNECTED
hostType         = WIRELESS
authType         = WPA2/WPA3+802.1x/FT-802.1x

connectedDevice  :
```

- Using member access `.userDetails` to select a child object (similar to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty userDetails`).
- Using `Format-List -Property` to output a list of the given properties
- Using `Out-String` to create a string from the formatting data that is produced by `Format-List`. This string looks exactly like the output you normally see on the console.
- Use `String` method `.Trim()` to remove whitespace (in this case newlines) from the beginning and end.
- Use the `-replace` operator to replace the first `:` of each line by `=`. See this [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yMZ1DS/1) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm assuming that you're looking for a friendlier *display representation* of  your data. For *programmatic processing*, `Format-*` cmdlets should be avoided, for the reasons explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).

---

**What you're looking for is for [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) to work *recursively***, i.e. to not only list the individual properties and their values for each input object itself, but also for *nested* objects contained in property *values*.

`Format-List` does *not* support this:

- Nested objects are represented by their single-line `.ToString()` representations.
- If they're part of a collection (enumerable), the individual elements' representations are joined with `,`  on a single line, and  are enclosed in `{...}`(!) as a whole. How many elements are shown at most is controlled by the [`$FormatEnumerationLimit` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#formatenumerationlimit), which defaults to `4`.

However, **you can *approximate* recursive listing behavior with [`Format-Custom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-custom)**; using a simplified example:

```bash
# Nested sample object to format.
[pscustomobject]@{
  userDetails = [pscustomobject] @{
    id = 'AA:BB:CC:DD:11:22'
    connectionStatus= 'CONNECTED'
    hostType        = 'WIRELESS'
    authType        = 'WPA2/WPA3+802.1x/FT-802.1x'
  }

  connectedDevice = '...'
} | 
  Format-Custom -Depth 1 # use higher -Depth levels for multi-level expansion
```

Output:

```
class PSCustomObject
{
  userDetails =
    [
      class PSCustomObject
      {
        id = AA:BB:CC:DD:11:22
        connectionStatus = CONNECTED
        hostType = WIRELESS
        authType = WPA2/WPA3+802.1x/FT-802.1x
      }
    ]

  connectedDevice = ...
}
```

Note:

- **Caveat**: If a *custom view* happens to be defined for a given input object's type via associated [formatting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml), it is that custom view that `Format-Custom` will invoke, not the structural representation shown above; however, this is rare (`[datetime]` is a rare example).
- Apart from the output showing the structure *recursively*, the format differs from that of `Format-List` as follows:

  - Complex objects are enclosed in `class <typeName> { ... }`
  - Elements of collections (enumerables) each render on their own (group of) line(s), enclosed in `[ ... ]` overall. However, as with `Format-List`, the number of elements that are shown at most is limited by `$FormatEnumerationLimit`.
- To prevent excessively nested output, `Format-Custom` stops recursing at a depth of `5` by default; you can control the recursion depth via the `-Depth` parameter, `1` meaning that only objects in immediate child properties are expanded.
- When the recursion depth limit is reached, non-collection objects are represented by their `.ToString()` representations, as with `Format-List`.