# Powershell Strings from Objects

Tags: string, powershell, object, variables

Trying to take an object and filter down to a value as a string. And save that string to variable and then use that variable in another command as a value for a flag.

So this command will get the PNPDevice InstanceID

```
$x = (Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly -Class 'Net' | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -EQ 'Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InstanceId | Format-Table -AutoSize | out-string )
```

Here I am checking the variable X and its content and type since the next command Disable-PNPDevice and the flag instanceID has to be a string

```
PS C:\Temp> $x.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                      
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                                                                                                                 



PS C:\Temp> echo $x
PCI\VEN_1234&DEV_543A&SUBSYS_32A39857&REV_04\3&1234839&0&C8
```

When I try to use $x for -InstanceId i get this error

```
PS C:\Temp> Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $x
Disable-PnpDevice : Invalid query 
At line:1 char:1
+ Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $x
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Win32_PnPEntity:ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity) [Disable-PnpDevice], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041017,Disable-PnpDevice
```

However if I manually create the variable with a string it works fine

```
PS C:\Temp> $y = "PCI\VEN_1234&DEV_543A&SUBSYS_32A39857&REV_04\3&1234839&0&C8"

PS C:\Temp> Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $y

PS C:\Temp> $y.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                      
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit `| Format-Table -AutoSize | out-string` from your command, which is not only redundant in your case (the `.InstanceId` property already *is* a string), but causes the instance ID string to have a *trailing newline*, which is likely the cause of your problem.

Generally:

- `Format-*` cmdlets emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: **only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.
- As an aside: That **`Out-String` blindly appends a trailing newline to its output string** is both unexpected and inconvenient: see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).

  - Note: With a *single* input object (such as in your case), `-NoNewLine` can be used to suppress the trailing newline (but `Out-String` is never needed for an input object that already *is* a string).
  - The problem is that with *multiple* input objects, `-NoNewLine` also suppresses newlines *between* their representations; e.g., `'one', 2 | Out-String -NoNewLine` yields verbatim `one2`

Comment: Thank so much that did the trick

$x = $(Get-PnpDevice -Class 'Net' | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -EQ 'Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InstanceId )

Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $x

Also as you mentioned the out-string command i recall the flag -NoNewLine

Comment: Glad to hear it, @JohnDoe. Please see my update re`-NoNewLine`.