# Issue with for each loop with Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, rest

I am currently having issues creating a powershell script that taks to an api with Invoke-RestMethod and a loop, I have spent all day trying to figure out where i am going wrong but i have not managed to come up with something.

Here is the code that i am trying to make

```
$url = "/api/Rest/v1"

$Body = @{
    Username = ""
    Password = ""
    Privatekey = ""
}

$apikey = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url/Authenticate -Body $body 

$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = $apikey

}

$allusers = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url/Users -Method Get -Headers $headers | ft -HideTableHeaders Id

foreach ($userid in $allusers)
{
echo $userid
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url/Users/$userid -Method Get -Headers $headers 
echo "test"
}
```

I am not having issues with the veriables $apikey and $allusers as they seem to output what i need but i think my issue is to do with the outbut being in format table but i have tried other methods for the for each and i have no clue where i am going wrong

So i have tested the Invoke-RestMethod commands on there own and they work as exspected but when i try the script above i get the following.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"Message":"User with specified id was not found."}
```

the output of $allusers displays something like the following for the user ID

```
dce502ed-e4b6-4b5e-a047-0bf3b34e98c6
dc1e60c1-99a7-479a-a7d6-0dc618c8dd5e
1bd98bb0-a9ee-46b5-8e2e-0e3146aab6b3
```

AKA the following work with no issues and outputs what i need

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url/Users/1bd98bb0-a9ee-46b5-8e2e-0e3146aab6b3 -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

I would really appreciate some kind of guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard advice applies:

- `Format-*` cmdlets (such as `Format-Table`, whose built-in alias is `ft`) emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system.
  In short: **only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display***, never for subsequent *programmatic processing* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.

Therefore, remove the `| ft -HideTableHeaders Id` pipeline segment and use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to extract all `.Id` property values *as data*.

```
$allusers = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url/Users -Method Get -Headers $headers).Id
```