# How do you sort a formatted table that uses a hash-table to create it?

Tags: powershell

In a nutshell I'm trying to get what would be the output of this command to run.

`Get-Process  | Format-Table | sort-object Handles`

Yes, I know you usually sort BEFORE Format-Table, but in this case I've created a hash-table within the `Format-Table` command that needs to be sorted.  The problem is, there is no way to sort with Format-Table that I can figure out.

I also considered trying to output the FT to CSV and then massaging it but that didn't work for me either.

I'm expecting to get a sorted table.

Comment: No that will not work because `Format-Table`'s intent is simply to display objects as Table to the console not mean to be sorted or exported

Answer (score 0):

> I've created a hash-table within the `Format-Table` command that needs to be sorted

By definition, you can *not* output a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) via any of the `-Format-*` cmdlets:

- `Format-*` cmdlets emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.

Assuming you've used [*calculated properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), with `Format-Table`, use them with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) instead, which produces *data* output, namely in the form of `[pscustomobject]` instances whose properties you can sort by, via [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object).

For instance, the following creates custom objects with `.Name` and `.MemUse` properties and sorts by the latter, then outputs the top 10 results:

```bash
Get-Process  | 
  Select-Object Name, @{ Name = 'MemUse'; Expression = 'WorkingSet64' } | 
  Sort-Object -Descending MemUse |
  Select-Object -First 10
```

Inverting the logic and letting `Sort-Object` operate on the *original* objects output by `Get-Process` is more efficient:

```bash
Get-Process  | 
  Sort-Object -Descending WorkingSet64 |
  Select-Object -First 10 |
  Select-Object Name, @{ Name = 'MemUse'; Expression = 'WorkingSet64' }
```

If you only care about *for-display* output, you can replace `Select-Object Name, ...` with `Format-Table -Name, ...` or `Format-List -Name, ...`, which illustrates an important point: `Format-*` calls should generally only come *last* in a pipeline.