# In PowerShell, how can I filter or select specific values in an expanded property

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Graph API to lookup user objects and the "registeredDevices" associated with that user. registeredDevices is a relational property so I'm using $exand.

My query

```
/users/<userId>`$expand=registeredDevices
```

is returning the properties I want (mail. jobTitle, id (user), and registeredDevices).

My problem is that registeredDevices is providing way more details then what I need...

```
registeredDevices : {@{@odata.type=#microsoft.graph.device; 
            id=AAA-1234; deletedDateTime=; accountEnabled=True; approximateLastSignInDateTime=2023-09-19T13:53:01Z; complianceExpirationDateTime=; createdDateTime=2022-07-25T13:08:38Z; 
                        deviceCategory=; deviceId=1234-ABCD; deviceMetadata=; deviceOwnership=; deviceVersion=2; displayName=<host name>; domainName=; enrollmentProfileName=; enrollmentType=; externalSourceName=; isCompliant=; isManaged=; 
                     isRooted=; managementType=; manufacturer=; mdmAppId=; model=; onPremisesLastSyncDateTime=; onPremisesSyncEnabled=; operatingSystem=Windows; operatingSystemVersion=10.0.19044.1766; physicalIds=System.Object[]; profileType=RegisteredDevice; 
                     registrationDateTime=2022-07-25T13:09:35Z; sourceType=; systemLabels=System.Object[]; trustType=Workplace; extensionAttributes=; alternativeSecurityIds=System.Object[]}, 

        @{@odata.type=#microsoft.graph.device; 
                    id=BBBB-1234; deletedDateTime=; accountEnabled=True; approximateLastSignInDateTime=2023-09-30T22:08:53Z; complianceExpirationDateTime=; createdDateTime=2023-09-21T14:19:08Z; deviceCategory=; 
                    deviceId=1234-BBBB; deviceMetadata=; deviceOwnership=Company; deviceVersion=2; displayName=<host name>; domainName=; enrollmentProfileName=LM US (Default); enrollmentType=AppleBulkEnrollmentModernAuth; 
                    externalSourceName=; isCompliant=True; isManaged=True; isRooted=False; managementType=MDM; manufacturer=Apple; mdmAppId=<value would be here>; <model=model name>; onPremisesLastSyncDateTime=; onPremisesSyncEnabled=; 
                    operatingSystem=Idevice; operatingSystemVersion=16.7; physicalIds=System.Object[]; profileType=RegisteredDevice; registrationDateTime=2023-09-21T14:19:08Z; sourceType=; systemLabels=System.Object[]; trustType=Workplace; extensionAttributes=; 
                    alternativeSecurityIds=System.Object[]}, 

        @{@odata.type=#microsoft.graph.device; id=CCCC-1234; deletedDateTime=; accountEnabled=True; approximateLastSignInDateTime=2023-09-30T20:54:47Z; complianceExpirationDateTime=; 
                    createdDateTime=2023-09-21T14:21:39Z; deviceCategory=; deviceId=1234-CCC; deviceMetadata=; deviceOwnership=Company; deviceVersion=2; displayName=<host name>; domainName=; enrollmentProfileName=<profile name>; 
                    enrollmentType=AppleBulkEnrollmentModernAuth; externalSourceName=; isCompliant=True; isManaged=True; isRooted=False; managementType=MDM; manufacturer=Apple; mdmAppId=<value would be here>; model=i<model name>; 
                    onPremisesLastSyncDateTime=; onPremisesSyncEnabled=; operatingSystem=Idevice; operatingSystemVersion=17.0.2; physicalIds=System.Object[]; profileType=RegisteredDevice; registrationDateTime=2023-09-21T14:21:39Z; sourceType=; 
                    systemLabels=System.Object[]; trustType=Workplace; extensionAttributes=; alternativeSecurityIds=System.Object[]}, 

        @{@odata.type=#microsoft.graph.device; id=DDDD-1234; deletedDateTime=; accountEnabled=True; 
                    approximateLastSignInDateTime=2023-10-01T21:00:36Z; complianceExpirationDateTime=; createdDateTime=2023-09-22T18:19:33Z; deviceCategory=; deviceId=1234-DDDD; deviceMetadata=; deviceOwnership=Company; deviceVersion=2; 
                    displayName=<model name>; domainName=; enrollmentProfileName=<profile name>; enrollmentType=AppleBulkEnrollmentModernAuth; externalSourceName=; isCompliant=True; isManaged=True; isRooted=False; managementType=MDM; manufacturer=Apple; 
                    mdmAppId=<value would be here>; model=<model name>; onPremisesLastSyncDateTime=; onPremisesSyncEnabled=; operatingSystem=Idevice; operatingSystemVersion=17.0.2; physicalIds=System.Object[]; profileType=RegisteredDevice; 
                    registrationDateTime=2023-09-22T18:20:02Z; sourceType=; systemLabels=System.Object[]; trustType=Workplace; extensionAttributes=; alternativeSecurityIds=System.Object[]}}
```

All I want from this property is any value starting with "id=". What would be the most efficient way to eliminate all the other stuff coming back?

I researched this the best i could and only found solutions that involve filtering out specific properties which i can already do. How do you filter out values of a property you don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using **[`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod)**, which  **automatically parses the API's JSON response into an object [graph]** - a potentially nested `[pscustomobject]` instance or an array thereof (in a manner of speaking, `Invoke-RestMethod` has [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) built in).

What you're seeing is the *for-display* representation of this object graph which shows that the top-level `[pscustomobject]` instance has a `.registeredDevices` property containing an array of nested `[pscustomobject]` instances, each of which has an `.id` property.

Therefore, taking advantage of [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), you can extract all nested `.id` property values as follows:

```bash
(
  Invoke-RestMethod ".../users/<userId>`$expand=registeredDevices"
).registeredDevices.id
```

Note:

- You can **reduce the amount of data transferred** by only **asking for the specific property/ies of interest**, such as by appending **`$select=id`** (`` `$select=id `` if inside `"..."`, e.g. `` ".../users/<userId>`$expand=registeredDevices&`$select=id" ``) to your query string - see [Project from an entity to properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/call-api#project-from-an-entity-to-properties).
- However, the **results are still *wrapped in objects*** (that also contain system properties such as `@odata.type`), so you still need the extraction technique shown above.

Comment: Thank you. I just figured this out. I was trying something like this before I posted and it wasn't working because I was piping to Format-List. Once I removed that, registeredDevices.id.Length started returning what I needed.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Jamie; if you're interested in why `Format-*` cmdlets should never be used for _programmatic_ processing, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375).