# Pull off all Windows 10 enabled PCs via PowerShell and export to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, automation

I would like to pull off all Windows 10 PCs that are enabled in my domain (filter/remove disabled PCs in the script) and would like the names and operating systems exported to CSV file, as I will be using this information copy the names of the PCs to add to GPOs. As I am in the progress of pushing GPO to all Windows 10 PCs.

If it is possible to add semi colon ";" after each name of PC so I can copy the text from the CSV as this will assist me when adding PCs to the GPO.

I currently have this command:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like '*Windows 10*'} -Properties * | FT Name, operatingsystem | 
Export-csv C:\Temp\Win10PCinAD.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

In the output of Powershell console this display all Windows 10 PC and the Operating System, when I copy direct from the console there is multiple spaces in the PC names also there are PCs in the output which are disabled, the CSV does not export the output correctly.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Change `FT` for `Select-Object`

Comment: You are the man sir!!!! Okay before you get angry at me (as I have done this in the past) Any chance of assisting with pulling only enabled Windows 10 PCs? As I can add the semi-colon in excel manually for each field myself (unless you can do this with your wizard scripting skills in PowerShell)

Comment: Just saw this sorry, so what you're missing right now is an additional filtering for Enabled Computer objects only right?

Comment: To elaborate on Santiago's comment: What `... | Format-Table` outputs isn't _data_ anymore; it is _objects that provide for-display formatting instructions_ to PowerShell, and they're only useful for that. Thus, if you want to capture _data_, for later _programmatic processing_, never capture the output from `Format-*` calls.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.

Comment: @S.Mahmood if you want to get just enabled computer you could just add that to your filter by checking that the value for `Enabled`  is `true`.  `{(OperatingSystem -like "*windows 10*") -and (Enabled -eq $true)} `

Comment: Thanks Santiago, MKlement0 and Kconsiglio! - after further investigation I found out you cant add multiple computers to a GPO MS will only allow single PC name at a time! So found another PS script can multiple PCs to a GPO https://gist.github.com/leeramsay/66e07cbe1f6173d010bd1c98661a3425 (Thanks to leeramsay on GITHUB) and tweaked script and the the PC output in Excel with formatting and managed to do it via that method BUT none the less people your help is always appreciated!! Thanks again!!