# how do I only output lines from a string array that contain a keyword match in two or more lines?

Tags: powershell, sorting, foreach

Using Compare-Object assigned to a variable:

```
    $diff = Compare-Object -referenceobject (Get-Content $hashlog1 -Encoding UTF8 | select -skip 1) -differenceobject (Get-Content $hashlog2 -Encoding utf8 | select -skip 1) | 
        Select @{N='Hash'; E={($_.InputObject -split ' ',2)[0] }}, @{N='File'; E={((($_.InputObject -split ' ',2)[1]) -split ' ' | select -skiplast 2) -join ' ' }}, @{N='SizeDate'; E={($_.InputObject -split ' ' | select -last 2) -join ' ' }}, SideIndicator | 
        Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096
```

Here is a sample log file call it `hashlog.txt` after a `compare-object`:

```
Hash                             File                                            SizeDate               SideIndicator
----                             ----                                            --------               -------------
D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E \added.txt                                      0 20230107_021401      =>           
6B7CA4894B3CFCBA1ECA6B8BB9656FE8 \dirsize2.bat                                   714 20231010_111350    =>           
804AB051DB174BF5FF53911647A094C2 \SSDTest ™\logfile.txt                          122644 20220806_221741 =>           
9266C28971E3624B28DAB39ADEE0694E \SSDTest ™\logfilemixed.txt                     14627 20220807_115714  =>           
4298F8C3383A93D121A1A91764492F93 \SSDTest ™\newfile.rtf                          42098 20231010_111523  =>           
1233EEF8C71A6AF8D23068CCDF1E639D \SSDTest ™\Samsung 850 EVO Small Files Only.txt 205671 20220805_224013 =>           
BD30A4E10CA22E3E3C6BA7063ACEBF0D \SSDTest ™\SSDCopy.bat                          269 20220731_172008    =>           
AF32AC8BEFDF8D3B63DE5D7B834709FD \SSDTest ™\SSDCopysmall.ps1                     1670 20220806_221654   =>           
AA7A12226FDD40671C191FAF6AA57733 \SSDTest ™\SSDCopy_Write_Read.bat               462 20220805_023811    =>           
3EDC4CE7B65FBC140B7D0F5604F3070D \SSDTest ™\SSDMixedWrite.ps1                    2476 20220807_115705   =>           
768B150D59F7EA576F375430883CC8DA \SSDTest ™\SSDRead.ps1                          2044 20220805_021614   =>           
B7D8DA3D9C1387EBCEC0565176385BB7 \SMR FINAL\SMR_PC_TEST_1_FILLRND.log            13014 20220823_134552  <=           
D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E \added.txt                                      0 20230107_021409      <=           
E17C51851C46801F9399087B61736E34 \dirsize2.bat                                   711 20230107_000101    <=           
E7A73A93D06EB266E614FC5110BBBF28 \SMR FINAL\SMR_PC_TEST_1_FILLRND.log            13014 20220822_133356  =>           
804AB051DB174BF5FF53911647A094C2 \SSDTest\logfile.txt                            122644 20220806_221741 <=           
9266C28971E3624B28DAB39ADEE0694E \SSDTest\logfilemixed.txt                       14627 20220807_115714  <=           
1233EEF8C71A6AF8D23068CCDF1E639D \SSDTest\Samsung 850 EVO Small Files Only.txt   205671 20220805_224013 <=           
AF32AC8BEFDF8D3B63DE5D7B834709FD \SSDTest\SSDCopysmall.ps1                       1670 20220806_221654   <=           
AA7A12226FDD40671C191FAF6AA57733 \SSDTest\SSDCopy_Write_Read.bat                 462 20220805_023811    <=           
3EDC4CE7B65FBC140B7D0F5604F3070D \SSDTest\SSDMixedWrite.ps1                      2476 20220807_115705   <=           
768B150D59F7EA576F375430883CC8DA \SSDTest\SSDRead.ps1                            2044 20220805_021614   <=
```

How can I go about outputting only entries that match two or more times based on `File` attribute? So, for example, the above log would result in the following:

```
D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E \added.txt                                      0 20230107_021401      =>           
D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E \added.txt                                      0 20230107_021409      <=           

6B7CA4894B3CFCBA1ECA6B8BB9656FE8 \dirsize2.bat                                   714 20231010_111350    =>           
E17C51851C46801F9399087B61736E34 \dirsize2.bat                                   711 20230107_000101    <=           

B7D8DA3D9C1387EBCEC0565176385BB7 \SMR FINAL\SMR_PC_TEST_1_FILLRND.log            13014 20220823_134552  =>           
E7A73A93D06EB266E614FC5110BBBF28 \SMR FINAL\SMR_PC_TEST_1_FILLRND.log            13014 20220822_133356  <=
```

I did attempt a nested `ForEach-Object` but that just output single matched files and didn't list both.

It seems like this should be straight forward, but it isn't. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

(If you're wondering about the "Trademark" Symbol ™ I was just making sure special characters were passing through)

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you. I assigned that `compare-object` output to `$diff` variable and ran `$diff | Group-Object File | Where-Object Count -gt 1` and it returned nothing.

Comment: @mklement0 - Thank you. I added the statement I used to generate the content for `$diff` so they should be objects. Unless I'm not understanding properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal **you need to be operating on *objects* with *distinct properties* instead of on *strings***:

> ```bash
> …| Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096
> ```

- `Format-*` cmdlets emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing*.
  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.
- By additionally using [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string), you end up with a *single, multiline string* that represents the original data in a format for *human*, not *programmatic* consumption.

Remove the `Format-Table` call from your pipeline - which results in *array* of *objects* - and then pipe `$diff` (or the modified pipeline directly) to [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) as follows:

```bash
$groups = 
  $diff | Group-Object File | Where-Object Count -ge 2
```

This groups all objects by shared `.File` property values and uses [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) to filter them so as to output only those groups with 2 or more elements.

Each group is an instance of type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo), whose `.Groups` property is a collection of all the elements in the group.

You can then use `$groups` to further process the groups programmatically; read on for how to *display* the resulting groups in a human-friendly fashion.

---

To *display* the resulting groups and their elements group by group, [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) *is* appropriate:

```bash
$diff | Group-Object File -OutVariable groups | Where-Object Count -ge 2 |
  ForEach-Object Group | Format-Table -GroupBy File
```

Note:

- [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `Group` (parameter `-MemberName` is implied) in essence undoes the grouping (it outputs the elements of each group one by one), only for the `-GroupBy` argument of `Format-Table` to group them again *for display* (there's no way around that, as `Format-Table -GroupBy` itself lacks any *filtering* capability).
- The [common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) is used to store the group objects in self-chosen variable `$groups` (note how the name is specified *without* the `$`), so that the groups can be programmatically processed later.

The above results in *for-display* output that:

- prints a header *between* groups showing the shared `.File` property value for each group
- prints a header *for each group*, namely the names of the properties being displayed and a separator line.

To *tweak* this format:

- Add `-HideTableHeaders` to omit the *for-each-group* headers.
- If you also want to omit the *between*-groups headers, more work is needed:

  ```bash
  $diff | Group-Object File -OutVariable groups | Where-Object Count -ge 2 |
    ForEach-Object {
      ($_.Group | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim()
      '' # Output an empty line between groups.
    }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Good catch on the `out-string`. How do I iterate through the Group then? I can run a `$diff | Group-Object File | Where-Object Count -ge 2 | % { $_.Group.Hash }` which will provide the hashes. But if I combine Hash and other attributes like `% { $_.Group.Hash $_Group.File $_.Group.SizeDate }` it errors out. I'm really trying to learn PS here on the go. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. `$groupdiff = $diff | group-object File | where-object count -ge 2; ForEach ($group in $groupdiff.group) { Write-Output "$($group.hash) $($group.file) $($group.sizedate)"}`. Now the next question is how do I put a blank line between each grouped set of duplicates?

Comment: I got it to display a blank line after each group by adding another variable `$fileprev=$null` then adding this to the `ForEach ($group in $groupdiff.Group)` loop: `if ($group.File -ne $fileprev) { Write-Output "" }; $fileprev=$group.File`

Comment: Thank you. Let me digest this for a bit and do some trial runs and I'll get back. Looks much cleaner than what I accomplished.

Comment: I more or less made use of what you suggested and got a working solution. I will go ahead and mark your response as accepted solution. Thank you for your prompt, polite, thorough, and useful response.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @HTWingNut; thanks for accepting and for the nice feedback.