# convert powershell object to a single field in a CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

The code below works perfectly fine to view the data on my screen but if I want to export it to a csv the fields for userRules and Last10email are blank. How would I convert the objects $userRules and $last10Email into blocks of text that will keep their formatting in my CSV (IE I want the whole table in a single field of the CSV)? I poked GPT with this but it just had me running in circles with suggestions that didn't work.

```
        # Get inbox rules for the user
    $userRules = Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $username | select Name, enabled, MoveToFolder, DeleteMessage, SoftDeleteMessage | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String

    # Get the last 10 emails for the user
    $last10EmailUTC = Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress $User -PageSize 10 |
        Select-Object -Property Received, SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, Subject |
        Sort-Object -Property Received -Descending | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String

    # Convert received timestamps to local time (PST)
    $last10Email = $last10EmailUTC | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Received -ne $null) {
            $_.Received = $_.Received.ToLocalTime().AddHours(-8)  # Subtract 8 hours for PST
        }
        return $_
    }

# Create and return a custom object
[PSCustomObject]@{
    userPrincipalName     = $user
    SamAccountName     = $userdetails.SamAccountName
    Name                  = $userdetails.Name
    employeeId             = $userdetails.employeeId
    Enabled               = $userdetails.Enabled
    localbadPwdCount           = $userdetails.BadLogonCount
    LastlocalBadPasswordAttempt = $userdetails.LastBadPasswordAttempt
    LastLocalLogonDate         = $userdetails.LastLogonDate
    PasswordExpired       = $userdetails.PasswordExpired
    PasswordLastSet       = $userdetails.PasswordLastSet
    userRules            = $userRules
    Last10email          = $last10Email

}
```

Comment: you're already using `| Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` so what you're doing should be working correctly displaying the representation of that table as single string. you need to explain what is not working (because your approach is correct in this case)

Comment: maybe you see them blank in Excel because you need to expand the row vertically (`Out-String` adds some extra spaces but you can `(.... | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).Trim()` to avoid that)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I knew stackoverflow wouldn't let me down. The Trim command did it and it works perfectly now. Thank You so much.

Comment: @RobynH, `.Trim()` isn't the only problem: `$_.Received -ne $null` is  _never_ `$true`, so your `ForEach-Object` call is in effect a _no op_: the dates are _not_ modified. You need to defer the `Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` call until _after_ your `ForEach-Object` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, you're already using `Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` to have the string representation of the table, the issue as confirmed in comments, is due to `Out-String` adding extra lines to your output.

You can solve this problem by trimming the outputted string:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    userPrincipalName           = $user
    SamAccountName              = $userdetails.SamAccountName
    Name                        = $userdetails.Name
    employeeId                  = $userdetails.employeeId
    Enabled                     = $userdetails.Enabled
    localbadPwdCount            = $userdetails.BadLogonCount
    LastlocalBadPasswordAttempt = $userdetails.LastBadPasswordAttempt
    LastLocalLogonDate          = $userdetails.LastLogonDate
    PasswordExpired             = $userdetails.PasswordExpired
    PasswordLastSet             = $userdetails.PasswordLastSet
    userRules                   = $userRules.Trim()                  # here
    Last10email                 = ($last10Email | Out-String).Trim() # and here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

- In the `$userRules = ...` assignment, make sure that `Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $username` produces actual output (note that you're using `$username` there vs. `$User` in the `Get-MessageTrace` call).

  - For the reasons explained below, you may want to apply `.Trim()` to `$userRules` before including it in the CSV:

    ```
      [pscustomobject] @{
        # ...
        userRules = $userRules.Trim()
        # ...
      }
    ```
- In the `last10emailUTC = ...` assignment, remove `| Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` from the end of your `Get-MessageTrace` pipeline to ensure proper object-oriented processing.

  - Then use the following as your CSV's property value:

    ```
      [pscustomobject] @{
        # ...
        Last10email = ($last10Email | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String).Trim()
        # ...
      }
    ```
  - In other words: **perform processing *on the original objects first*, and only *then* convert them to a string representation** with `Out-String`.

---

###### Background information:

- Generally, `Format-*` cmdlets emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, not for subsequent *programmatic processing*.
  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.
- However, since you're piping `Format-Table` to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string), you do get data, but in the form of the input objects' *for-display representation*, as a *single, multiline string*.

  - In other words: You'll get the same *for-display* representation you would if you output directly to the host (console).
  - This may be sufficient in your case, but it is worth pointing out that these representations are not generally suited to *programmatic* processing, except in simple cases, such as "primitive" objects such as numbers or strings (objects representing a *single value*).

    - Also, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, the resulting multiline string for "complex" objects usually has leading and trailing *empty lines* that you may want to trim with `(... | Out-String).Trim()`
- If `$userRules` ends up empty (`$null`), the implication is that `Get-InboxRule -Mailbox $username` produced no output.
- `$last10Email` is predictably *always* `$null`, however:

  - In the assignment, an attempt is made to process `$last10EmailUTC` *element by element* via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), with an attempt to access a `.Received` property on each.
  - However, due to use of `Out-String`, `$last10EmailUTC` is a *single string*, and strings have no `.Received` property, resulting in a `$null` value.

    - `$_.Received -ne $null` is therefore *never* `$true`, and your `ForEach-Object` call is in effect a *no-op*: no dates are ever modified.
    - As an aside: By default, PowerShell quietly returns `$null` for attempts to access nonexistent properties, but you can use `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher to report an error instead).
  - To make your code work as intended:

    - Remove `| Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` from the end of your `Get-MessageTrace` pipeline, so that `$last10EmailUTC` receives an *array of objects*, which are then processed properly by your subsequent `ForEach-Object` call.
    - Only *afterwards* does it make sense to apply `Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` in order to obtain a (for-display) string representation.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're outputting the CSV in a way similar to this:

```
$yourCustomObject | Export-Csv -Path .\filename.csv -Delimiter ','
```

Make sure to set/choose a delimiter that doesn't appear in any of your fields.

If that doesn't fix your issue, we'll need more information about what exactly is not working and possibly some output that is currently generated.

Comment: `Export-Csv` default delimiter is `,`. This is not OPs issue.

Comment: I'm well aware of `,` being the default delimiter. But especially when working with csv files delimiters can be an issue. We don't know the true contents of the fields and `,` is a character that could easily appear in the subject of an email or other fields.
Although you're correct that it obviously wasn't OPs issue, as that'd only result in more columns than expected instead of seemingly blank fields.

Comment: `Export-Csv` adds quotes to the fields so that shouldn't be an issue either